# My custom heroku python buildpack downloads requirements on every push

Tags: python, django, heroku, buildpack

I forked the default python buildpack and added a few lines which basically add the phantonjs and casperjs executables to my environment. Code here: https://github.com/tapanpandita/heroku-buildpack-python .The changes I made are minimal (from line 163-196 here https://github.com/tapanpandita/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/compile#L163).

However, now, the problem is that when I push to heroku master, all the requirements are downloaded again. This makes the deployment process very slow. This wasn't a problem before when I was using the default buildpack. Any idea what i might have done wrong? It's a django app.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your buildpack so that you can vendor the phantomjs and casperjs executables in your repo.